# exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException runtime error

Tags: java

I am quite bad at object-oriented programming, and I need help solving what is causing this runtime error. I know it's probably something simple, so please do not get mad at me for my incompetence. I appreciate your time.

Here is the code:

```
import static java.lang.System.out; 
import java.util.Scanner;

class FormulaMethods {
void Force() {

    double mass, acceleration, answer;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    out.println("You have chosen the F=MA (Find Force) Formula.");
    out.println("Enter Mass Value: ");
    mass = input.nextDouble();
    out.println("Enter acceleration value: ");
    acceleration = input.nextDouble();
    answer = mass * acceleration;
    out.printf("The Force of these given variables is: %lf", answer);
    }
}
```

AND

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

class FormulaCalculator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        int formula = choice.nextInt();
        FormulaMethods form = new FormulaMethods();

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Physics Formula Calculator Tool!");
    System.out.println("Please choose the number for the formula you would like to calculate: ");
    switch (formula) {
        case 1:
            form.Force();
            break;

        default: 
            System.out.println("No such option even exists, dimwit.");
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

No compilation errors, but i do get this:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at FormulaCalculator.main(FormulaCalculator.java:7)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This exception is caused due to Scanner class method nextInt as there is no data. First check if the data is available by using Scanner class method hasNext().

Comment: Now im getting this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at FormulaCalculator.main(FormulaCalculator.java:7)

Comment: You might be giving non integer input( may be a new line or something) which nextInt is not accepting. Using try catch for your nextInt line might help.

Comment: No, like, the program doesnt run at all when I type java FormulaCalculator in the console after compilation. It just does nothing until i type something, and then it prints out above error.

Comment: nvm, figured it out. turns out it was scanning before it printed out the initialization statement. I'm a dimwit.